# How to normalize data with semesters vs trimesters when all mixed in dataset in R

Tags: r

I am new to R but finding it a powerful solution when working with education data across a state. I have grades for about 11,000 students over the span of two years. Most students 12 rows in my dataset, as most schools work on a semester system. Many schools, however, work on a trimester or quarter system, meaning there are more or less rows and, therefore, more or less grades. The grades are relatively close throughout each semester/trimester/whatever and I have already converted the letter grade into a numeric value. A column titled 'TERM' identifies which system the school is under (SEM1/2, TRI1/2/3, QTR1/2/3/4). I am wondering if anyone has an idea as to how best organize this data by TERM so I have something normalized.

```
df<- cbind(c('stu1', 'stu1', 'stu2','stu2','stu2'), c('sem1','sem2', 'tri1','tri2','tri3'), c('a','c','a','b','a'), c(4,2,4,3,4))
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example so that we can have a look and help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: What exactly is your end goal? Just to organize the data by term and normalize so that it's on the same scale? Or do you intend on running some analysis once your data is normalized? I ask as this info could potentially aid in providing you with an answer.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of example. Working on getting something simple up but this is my first post so it's slow going. My end goal is to find the average grade for each student. I have already figured out how to turn the letter grades into a number. I just need to figure out how to get script written so that the SEM1 and SEM2 for a student gets averaged and the TRI1, TRI2, and TRI3 all get averaged. Once it is all averaged, I can just remove duplicates and have one row for each student with one grade to represent their performance during the year. Thanks so much!!